# installing Docker community edition fails with missing docker-ce package

Tags: software-installation, release-hera

I'm using Hera and would like to install Docker. I followed the install instructions

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

starting at **Install using the repository**. I'm getting stuck at point two of **INSTALL DOCKER ENGINE - COMMUNITY**. When running

`$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

I get the following error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
```

Maybe the problem is related to this one here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030179/package-docker-ce-has-no-installation-candidate-in-18-04

If you would like to see my installation process for reproduction:

https://hatebin.com/fmvfvfysqc

1. How can I solve the problem and get the docker community edition?
2. I installed some dependencies and maybe I will get problems if I install other dependencies now. It would be awesome if you would provide a cleanup if your solution requires different installations :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions point to adding their repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

In elementary OS, `lsb_release -cs` will output `hera`, for which that repository does not contain anything.

[image]

But, as elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, you can easily replace `hera` with `bionic`, like this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
```

So, if you follow the instructions on their site, you'll end up with an incorrect repository in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hera stable
```

To fix this, edit the file and replace `hera` with `bionic`.

Run a `sudo apt update` and make sure it outputs no errors.
Now, `sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io` runs as expected:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount pigz
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli pigz
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 85,5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 384 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

After the installation completes, running `docker -v`:
`Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838`

They do state this in the instructions:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed description

Comment: I have Linux Mint 19.3, When I run the command `sudo add-apt-repository ...` I get this error: `Malformed input, repository not added.
`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing it with a downloaded .deb installer? It seems that the cli file is sometimes inaccessible due to lack of support for a particular OS.

Or have you tried using:
sudo apt install docker.io

Comment: sorry no, I didn't try. Do I have to rollback the installation before trying?

Comment: I installed with apt directly before but it is v18 instead of the 19 I would get with their repo